# Add CSS file to webpack compilation from a loader

Tags: webpack

I'm creating a webpack loader that will process JS files and in certain cases I want to add CSS files to the compilation. The CSS file contains global CSS so it doesn't need to be treated as a CSS module.

Unfortunately I can't inject an import statement into the JS file because Next.js doesn't allow it in files inside node_modules.

I've come as far as creating a `NormalModule` instance which I pass to `this._compilation.addModule()` but the `NormalModule` class expects a generator instance to be passed in, and I'm stuck on trying to get a hold of such a generator class for css files.

Am I even on the right path here?